# How can I force a connection to a specific WiFi network using nmcli?

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, nmcli, essid

NetworkManager is often extremely slow to scan and detect new networks with my wireless card ([`rtl8xxxu` driver](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtl8xxxu)).

Using the Network Manager GUI I can "force" a connection to a specific wireless network using "Connect to a Hidden Network". Even if NetworkManager hasn't yet detected a particular SSID, it will try (and succeed) at connecting to the indicated network:

[image: networking menu]

However, I haven't found a way to emulate this from the command line:

```
$ nmcli c up id ConnectionNameOrID
Error: Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection.

$ nmcli d wifi connect NetworkName password 'PSKPassword'
Error: No network with SSID 'NetworkName' found.
```

This is frustrating! Obviously, NetworkManager has *some* API that allows it to try connecting to an as-yet-unscanned network. Is there any way for me to access this from `nmcli` or another command-line tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `nmcli connection up $NAME ifname $IFACE`?

`nmcli device wifi connect` creates a new connection, also it expects as argument an SSID, not a connection (name).

Comment: Hey, that does the trick! I had no idea that adding the `ifname` argument would force it to try that interface. Maybe this should be suggested for the `nmcli` docs.